# Null pointer while trying to read xml with boost

Tags: c++, xml, boost

I stumbled upon an interesting problem. I have managed to reduce the problem to the following code:

```
boost::property_tree::ptree properties;
boost::property_tree::read_xml("Additional Dependencies\\properties.xml", properties);
```

xml:

```
<Properties>

  <PictureGenerator>
    <miniatureHeight>4</miniatureHeight>
    <miniatureWidth>4</miniatureWidth>

    <imageHeight>8</imageHeight>
    <imageWidth>8</imageWidth>

    <ImagePath>Additional Dependencies\</ImagePath>
    <Miniatures>
      <Image>0.bmp</Image>
      <Image>1.bmp</Image>
      <!--<Image>2.bmp</Image>
      <Image>3.bmp</Image>
      <Image>4.bmp</Image>-->
    </Miniatures>

  </PictureGenerator>
</Properties>
```

When i build the project in Release mode, everything runs perfectly.
In Debug mode I get the following error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x779e8e19 in my_project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000014.
```

I am using VS2010.
Upon further inspection the error is thrown in the read_xml_internal function while trying to create a vector from a basic_istream.
At first I thought that I gave the wrong path, but I works perfectly in Release mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the source of the problem.
I have reproduced the same error with istream, and it turned out that I had a wrong property page set for Debug.

The problem was the property:

```
C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Libary as Multi-threaded
```

I have changed it to `Multi-threaded Debug Dll` and it works perfectly.